# Existence of a pointwise convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f_m:X\to[0,1]$ a continuous function for each $m\in\mathbb N$.

> Does there necessarily exist a $f:X\to[0,1]$ (not necessarily continuous) and a subsequence $(f_{m_k})$ such that $f_{m_k}(x)\to f(x)$ for each $x\in X$ pointwise?

Note that the equicontinuity of $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ is not assumed, so that the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem is of no use here. However, the desired conclusion is also weaker: the supposed limit function $f$ need not be continuous and only pointwise convergence is required.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: $X$ has a countable dense subset. Perhaps you could define $f$ there first?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that’s a good idea for a first step. If $\{x^1,x^2,\ldots\}$ is dense, then, by Cantor’s diagonal method, there is a subsequence such that $f_{m_k}(x^j)$ converges as $k\to\infty$ for every $j\in\mathbb N$. Using this result, the next step would be showing that $f_{m_k}(x)$ is Cauchy in $[0,1]$ for each $x\in X$, but it seems tricky, as convergence at the $x^j$s need not be uniform.

Comment: Robert has a nice counterexample below.

Comment: If functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ are nondecreasing in x for each n, then (regardless of continuity or behavior with n) your argument of showing convergence over a subsequence on a countable but dense subset can be used to prove convergence everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The same does _not_ hold for functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,1]$ that are entrywise nondecreasing as we can have discontinuity across a diagonal and then adapt one of the 1-d counterexamples given below on that diagonal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A similar example using more machinery hence  perhaps less tricky in the details: Let $X=[0,2\pi]$, $f_n(t)=\cos(nt)$.  If $f_{n_k}(x)\to f(x)$ for (almost) every $x$ then Dominated Convergence shows that $||f_{n_k}-f||_2\to0$; this is impossible by orthogonality (for example, $||f_n-f_m||_2^2=2\pi$.)

Answer (score 10):

No, there does not.  Consider $f_n(x) = \cos(4^n \pi x)$ on $[0,1]$ (with range in $[-1,1]$ not $[0,1]$, but you can transform it).  Then for any subsequence $f_{n_k}$, there is 
some $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f_{n_k}(x) \ge \cos(\pi/4)$ if $k$ is odd and $\le -\cos(\pi/4)$ if $k$ is even. All you need to do is choose the base-$4$ digits of $x$ correctly.

EDIT: Any choice of the first $n$ digits after the "decimal" point leaves $x$ in an interval of length $4^{-n}$ on which $f_n$ goes either from $1$ to $-1$ or $-1$ to $1$.  Choose the $n+1$'th digit to be $0$ or $3$ to make $f_n(x) \ge \cos(\pi/4)$ or $\le -\cos(\pi/4)$ (which is which depends on the previous choices of digits).  For example, if you choose the first $3$ digits to be $0,3,0$,  that says $x$ is between $0 \times 4^{-1} + 3 \times 4^{-2} + 0 \times 4^{-3} = 3/16$ and $0 \times 4^{-1} + 3 \times 4^{-2} + 1 \times 4^{-3} = 13/64$,
say $x = 3/16 + 4^{-3} t$, $0 \le t \le 1$.  On this interval, $f_3(x) = \cos(4^3 \pi x) = \cos(\pi t)$ goes from $1$ at $t=0$ to $-1$ at $t=1$.  If you want $f_3(x) \ge \cos(\pi/4)$, choose the $4$'th digit to be $0$, if you want $f_3(x) \le - \cos(\pi/4)$ choose the $4$'th digit to be $3$.

Comment: What do mean by "choose the base-$4$ digits of $x$ correctly"? Could you illustrate it with an example please? For instance the case where $n_k=k$. How do you construct $x$? Thanks.

Comment: +1 Great answer, thank you! I accepted David C. Ullrich’s answer relying on $L^2$ theory because I have found it to be more straightforward (albeit less elementary or creative) than yours.